# How to Upload additional images in to html5 & javascript slideshow

Tags: javascript, css, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Slideshow</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slideshow.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
var imagecount = 1;
var total = 6;

function slide(x) {
var Image = document.getElementById('img');
imagecount = imagecount + x;
if(imagecount > total){ imagecount = 1;}
if(imagecount < 1){ imagecount = total;}
Image.src = "Images/img"+ imagecount +".jpg";
}

</script>
</head>

//div id sections are also formatted through css
<body>
<div id="container">\
<img src="Images/img1.jpg" id="img"/>
<div id="left_holder"> <img onClick="slide(x-1)" class="left"         src="arrowleft.jpg"/></div>
<div id="right_holder"> <img onClick="slide(1)" class="right"      src="arrowright.jpg"/></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

IS there any way I can add maybe an 'addLoadEventToFileSelect' & would this be the correct way to do so

Comment: how do you use slide() function. please provide complete code.

Comment: That is the complete code - Would it help if i provided my css for yourself to test?

Comment: @guest271314 you are a legend mate. Thank You !!!!!!!